# Filtering set by classes information

Tags: rascal

Suppose I want to get all fields from some OFG g while ignoring fields like  `|java+field:///java/lang/System/err|`. How do I check whether the resulting field actually refers to some class from the imported project?

My attempt is this. Here the compiler lights up at `<- classes`. So it doesn't allow `from.path`. Which I think should be possible.

```
g = buildGraph(createOFG(|project://eLib|));
m = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://eLib|);
set[str] classes = { cl.path | cl <- classes(m) };
set[loc] fields = { from | <from,_> <- g, 
                       from.scheme == "java+field", from.path <- classes };
```

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: `from.path` is not a pattern syntax, so you can use a variable instead:

```
 set[loc] fields = { from | <from,_> <- g, 
                   from.scheme == "java+field", x <- classes, x == from.path };
```

or

```
 set[loc] fields = { from | <from,_> <- g, 
                   from.scheme == "java+field", x := from.path, x <- classes };
```

A nice solution to the problem could be to use the containment relation `m@containment`, if you transitively close it `m@containment*` and query from the top you know if something is in the project, like `myField in m@containment*[ |java+package:///elib|]`.

It's good to keep the `m@containment*[ |java+package:///elib|]` around in a variable since it is an expensive computation.

You can find out what the top of the containment relation is like so:

```
rascal> import analysis::graphs::Graph; // or import Graphs; in older versions
ok
rascal> top(m@containment)
set[loc]: {
   |java+package:///org|,
   |java+package:///vinju|
}
```